# Mysteriously persistent ClassNotFoundException (Main Activity)

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, classnotfoundexception

I've been reading the solutions from others who've had this problem and most answers state that its a problem with the manifest, but I can't see any problems in mine..it looks accurate yet I keep getting a ClassNotFoundException upon run.

SongbirdActivity.java:

```
package com.songbirdapp.songbird;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SongbirdActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.songbirdapp.songbird"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SongbirdActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Can anyone see a problem here?

LOGCAT output:

```
01-30 15:28:21.622: D/AndroidRuntime(1315): Shutting down VM
01-30 15:28:21.692: W/dalvikvm(1315): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.songbirdapp.songbird/com.songbirdapp.songbird.SongbirdActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.songbirdapp.songbird.SongbirdActivity
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.songbirdapp.songbird.SongbirdActivity
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-30 15:28:21.712: E/AndroidRuntime(1315):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Weird... That Manifest looks fine to me. Try to rebuild your project from scratch

Comment: Thank you for the edit Guillaume...was having trouble getting it right

Comment: Just add 4 blank spaces in front of each line (to get code formatting on blocks)

Comment: By "rebuild from scratch" do you mean create a new project and copy all the assests over?

Comment: No, no, just tell whatever IDE you're using (I'm guessing Eclipse?) to rebuild your project, i.e. delete classes and recompile (don't know the exact command as I use IntelliJ)

Comment: Tried rebuilding...same error. Maybe I should generate a new main activity and manifest from a sample template and see if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has defied all attempts to answer it. I'm going to nuke the project and start over, then just copy and paste the old code over.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this same behavior, and what finally solved it for me was making sure that when I went to export the apk, there was not an existing apk file with that same name in the location.  When there was (for example, exporting after a small change) the apk would often end up being a noticeably smaller size (~600k vs ~720k) and, once started, would often result in this CallNotFoundException.

Once I was sure to delete the existing APK before export, I stopped having this pesky issue.

Maybe this will help someone else.

Eclipse 4.2.0 on Windows 7
ADT 21.0.0